# When applying diffusion to an image, how to control the dither "percentage," like Photoshop does?

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library

To apply diffusion to an image, one may use an algorithm like Floyd Steinberg (FS), but how to control the "percentage" of the dithering like Photoshop has an option in the legacy "Save for Web" feature? In Python, with PIL, one can use im.convert('1') to convert an image to black and white and apply FS dithering automatically. But it seems the dithering would be 100%. I'd like it to more closely match the Photoshop effect of 88%. How to achieve that? (using a library or modifying the FS algorithm)

[image]

Examples of the impact of dither % on the image (generated via Photoshop):

Dither 25%:

[image: Dither 25%]

Dither 50%:

[image]

Dither 75%:

[image]

Dither 100%:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Photoshop's diffusion. Can you give an explanation of the behavior you're used to with Photoshop, when you set the percentage lower? Does it dither only part of the image? Does it do some sort of fade between the dithered image and the non-dithered one? Maybe you can give a series of images demonstrating no dither, full dither, and various percentages like 25%, 50%, and 75%?

Comment: @B.Eckles, thanks for the feedback, I added that to the post.

Comment: Thanks, @E.W. Hm, that's fascinating. First two ideas which come to mind are that they're changing the amount of error being pushed onto neighboring cells (in Floyd-Steinberg), or else they're doing something like scaling the image colors before applying the algorithm.

Comment: Searching around, I've found one slight reference to something they might be doing: https://www.dynamicpdf.com/Support/NET_Help_Library_16_06/DynamicPDFRasterizerProgrammingWithDithering_.html It talks about the "number of pixels" which are dithered. Not really sure what that means, but it might help give you/someone/us an idea.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of info on this page which I haven't had time to read, but in particular see the linked section: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#monochrome That, combined with the previous link I posted, gives me the idea that perhaps the percentage controls what percentage of "middle" colors get dithered. In other words, if colors are above or below a certain threshold, they are simply set to the upper or lower extreme. If they're within that middle area though, they are dithered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's going on in Photoshop, but from my searchings and as I described a bit in the comments on the question, I've got an idea which seems valid. So this might not be the right answer, but it might be a similar sort of answer.

I'll describe the idea in a grayscale-to-monochrome (mapping the interval `[0,1]` to the set `{0,1}`) case, which could of course be extrapolated to a color case.

Let `p` be the desired percentage (such that `p` is in `[0,1]`). The algorithm would be to perform Floyd-Steinberg, but only push error onto neighbors which are in the interval `[(1-p)/2, (1-p)/2 + p]`. So if all of my neighbors are outside of that range, my error just gets thrown away. Otherwise, my error gets pushed onto whichever ones are within that range (with the same proportions Floyd-Steinberg usually specifies).

I'm dithering on whether that will yield the desired result (I'm not 100% sure), but it seems at least similar. Let me know how your investigation goes!

Comment: One other idea would be to filter the image before performing the Floyd Steinberg. Increase contrast, for instance, to obtain a "lower percentage dither", and decrease it to obtain a higher percentage. No idea if it would give the desired result, but it's another place to explore.